# How do I save Images of objects I just rendered?

Tags: maxscript

I am new to scripting and I'm, trying to export objects in my scene and render images of all selected objects individually.

Right now my code can only export FBX files based on whatever name my object has and can render one image.

```
for current in geometry do
(
    select current
    newFileName = current.name
    newFilePath = pathConfig.GetDir #Export
    completeFilePath = (newFilePath + "/" + newFileName)

    exportFile completeFilePath #noPrompt selectedOnly:true using:FBXEXP
    render renderType:#selected 
    --render current frame:1 outputfile:"testRender.png"
)
```

I want to export, render each selected object (individually) in my scene, save it as .png, and use the object's name on the rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for current in geometry do
(
    select current
    newFileName = current.name
    newFilePath = pathConfig.GetDir #Export
    completeFilePath = (newFilePath + "/" + newFileName)

    exportFile completeFilePath #noPrompt selectedOnly:true using:FBXEXP
    render renderType:#selected

    outputFilePath = (newFilePath + "/" + newFileName + ".png")
    render current frame:1 outputfile:outputFilePath 
)
```